# I am dispatching a request from a servlet to jsp, do they run in the same thread?

Tags: multithreading, jsp, servlets

1. I dispatch a request from a servlet to jsp.
2. Now the jsp is converted to a servlet by the container (like Tomcat).
3. Then HTML file is generated and is rendered in the browser.

My question is: Are steps 1 & 2 executed in the same thread?

Comment: Yes; the JSF framework (for example) relies on this being so.

Comment: 'jsp gets rendered in browser on client side' is incorrect Rai as the container will generate the HTML (commonly HTML or other format) and this gets sent to the broswer which the browser loads (DOM). Edit: Just realised that the previous answer is deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Servlets 2.5 specification does not define such case from concurrent processing perspective. Therefore the answer depends on a Container implementation.

The Servlets 3.0 specification defines the asynchronous servlets. Those servlets can perform async dispatching, which results in spawning several threads working in parallel. So, the answer is definitely NO for servlets with async support which perform async dispatching.